# how can i access an element of a vector of structures

Tags: c++

I'm doing this simple exercise where I need to create a list of books and then remove or add them...
the problem is that for some reason I can't access the structure that I made.
PD: I tried with arrays and it worked perfect, but I need dynamic memory because I don't know how many books they may want to put in the list. 
I am very noob so forgive me if this sounds stupid.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
struct book{
    string name;
    string autor;
    string type;
};

void addbook(vector<book> x){
    x.push_back(book());
    cout<<"the name of the book"<<endl;
    cin>>x.back().name;
    cout<<"the name of the autor"<<endl;
    cin>>x.back().autor;
    cout<<"the type of the book"<<endl;
    cin>>x.back().type;
}
int main() {;
    vector<book> list;
    addbook(list);
    cout<<list[0].name;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. You're question was well presented, but it'd be even better if your code was in English. People are more likely to read/respond/upvote if your question/examples are as simple as possible.  =)

Comment: thanks for the advice... I already edited it.

Comment: Hi - sorry about this. I upvoted because you changed it to English, but actually I should've said in my last comment that it's probably too late to make the change because others have already answered with your original code namings. My previous comment was more for your future posts. Sorry! Now I feel bad! Haha.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't fix the bugs in your code in your original question. This makes answers out-of-date and effectively makes a completely new question. The bugs or any bad code choices might be useful for others who have similar problems in the future, so you should have kept your vector as local **and** global. However, just keep this in mind for future, because I see that others have already edited their answers in response.

Comment: Edits are there more for clarity, and should typically be done so as not to make any answers obsolete, so usually better to be done soon after posting. If you want to know what to do if you take the advice of answer but still have problems, try leaving a comment to explain what you tried and the problems you had. Sometimes you'll need to show your code for this, and if it's more than one or two lines of code it's probably more appropriate to edit your original question by **appending** the question (users typically write **EDIT** at the beginning of an appended edit so other users know).

Comment: ok! sorry for that...it won't happen again.

Comment: No need to apologise. It was your first question. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is global variable with name 'lista' and you are using the same name for another vector in main. If you declare a variable with the same name as global variable inside a function, the local variable hides global variable inside the function. So your main() is referring to local variable but LibroALeer() function is referring to global variable. That means you are pushing the values to global vector inside LibroALeer() and you are trying to print local variable inside main() which doesn't have any value inside the vector.

Please refer below code to fix the problem

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
struct book{
    string name;
    string autor;
    string type;
};

void addbook(vector<book> &x){
    x.push_back(book());
    cout<<"the name of the book"<<endl;
    cin>>x.back().name;
    cout<<"the name of the autor"<<endl;
    cin>>x.back().autor;
    cout<<"the type of the book"<<endl;
    cin>>x.back().type;
}
int main() {;
    vector<book> list;
    addbook(list);
    cout<<list[0].name;
    return 0;
}
```

In your code, you are passing the vector using 'pass by value' which means a copy of the vector is created for addbook() function. So you are pushing the contents to the copy not to the original vector. To fix this issue, you need to use 'pass by reference' which means copy won't be created.

```
void addbook(vector<book> x) // pass by value
void addbook(vector<book> &x) // pass by reference
```

Comment: thanks but I change it and the problem seems the same.... see the edited code that I made.

Comment: thaaaaaanks! the problem was the "&" I find very confusing when I need or not to put the addresses and the pointers

Comment: @clementearanguiz: Glad it helped you.

Answer (score 4):

You have global `lista` and another one local to `main`. `LibroALeer()` is using the global one, `main` is using the local one. If you get rid of the local one, things should work.

Comment: Even better: Keep it local and send it to the LibroALeer function

Comment: You're passing a *copy* of the vector to your function. You want to pass a *reference* instead: `void addbook(vector<book>& x)`

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using global variable. You are traversing multiple times in LibroALeer(), it can be improved like so:

```
//vector<libro> lista;  //Avoid global variable

void LibroALeer(vector<libro>& lista){
    libro libro1;        
    cout << "Introduzca el nombre del libro"<<endl;
    cin >> libro1.nombre;
    cout << "Introduzca el nombre del autor"<<endl;
    cin >> libro1.autor;
    cout << "Introduzca el nombre del genero del libro"<<endl;
    cin >> libro1.genero;
    lista.push_back(libro1);
}
int main() {
    vector<libro> lista;
    LibroALeer(lista);
    cout<<lista[0].nombre;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I agree that the local variable is better,  but is your code more efficient? `std::list::back()` has constant time complexity. Also, the original version is likely optimised by the compiler to make an `emplace_back()`, so no copying of the struct, but your version would make it harder for the compiler to deduce that a copy is unnecessary.